# Process lines with different sizes to csv

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert a PDF bank extract to csv. I'm fairly new into python, but I managed to extract text from pdf. I'm ended with something similar to this:

AMAZON 23/12/2019 15:40 -R$ 100,00 R$ 400,00 credit
Some Restaurant 23/12/2019 14:00 -R$ 10,00 R$ 500 credit
Received from John Doe 22/12/2019 15:00 R$ 510 R$ 500,00
03 Games 22/12/2019 15:00 R$ 10 R$ 10,00 debit

I want this output:
AMAZON;23/12/2019;-100,00
Some Restaurant;23/12/2019;-10,00
Received from John Doe;22/12/2019;510
03 Games;22/12/2019;10

First field have different sizes, I don't need time and currency format. I don't need last 2 fields.

I have this code so far (just extracting text from PDF):

```
import pdfplumber
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]
pdf = pdfplumber.open(url)
pdf_pages = len(pdf.pages)

for i in range(pdf_pages):
    page = pdf.pages[(i)]
    text = page.extract_text()
    print(text)
pdf.close()
```

Can anyone give some directions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this the split method. To split the strings into lines and into the separate parts and pick then the parts.

The following link explains it very nicely.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_ref_string_split

```py
lines:List[str] = text.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    entries:List[str] = line.split()
    date_entry_index: int = get_date_index(entries)
    name = entries[0]
    for index in range(1, date_entry_index + 1):
        name += " " + entries[index]
    print(f"{name};{entries[date_entry_index]};{entries[date_entry_index + 2]}")

def get_date_index(entries_check:List[str]) -> int:
    # either you could use the function below or you check if the entry only contains digits and "/"
    for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
        if len(entry) == 10:
            continue
        if entry[2] != "/" or entry[5] != "/":
            continue
        # here you could check if the other parts of the date are digits or some letters or something similar.
        return index
    else:
        raise ValueError("No Date found")
```

That should print it.

Comment: It's getting better. 

The problem with this approach is that lines have different sizes and thus while in one line entys[1] is the date on the other is not.

I think split separated using spaces, but this file doesn't have any field separator.

Comment: Do the dates always have length of 10?
If thats the case you could check for the slash on position 2 and 5 and find the date Position with a very high degree of certenty.

Comment: yes, dates have lenght of 10 (including /) in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy. I'll check what you proposed!
Thank you, very, very much.